# Issue with a subquery MySQL 5.5 vs 5.6

Tags: mysql, percona

I have been running a website on MySQL 5.5 (percona) and using this query, which works:

```
SELECT
    bds.FromStationPositionID
FROM
    BusDestinationSegments AS bds
LEFT JOIN BusDestinationSegmentPrices AS bdsp ON bds.SegmentID = bdsp.BusDestinationSegmentID
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        BusDestinationScheduleID
    FROM
        BusDestinationSchedule
    WHERE
        BusDestinationScheduleDate + INTERVAL bdssf.DayOfset DAY = '2016-01-26'
),
 BusDestinationStations AS bdssf
```

I needed to upgrade to 5.6 (again Percona) so I just did (on a development server).
However, this query now does not work. It tells me:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'bdssf.DayOfset' in 'where clause'
```

I should add that I've checked and the column is there.

I'm guessing there is some kind of change from 5.5 to 5.6 which does not allow me to use columns in sub-queries, but I can't find anything on the topic.

Has anyone had any experience with this or can anyone suggest a way that what I'm trying to accomplish will work ?

Comment: Have you tried using just `BusDestinationStations.Dayofset` does it is working?

Comment: It works in a different query, but using it like that in this query would mean another instance of the table, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish. Even so, it does not work with "BusDestinationStations" - it says Unknown column 'BusDestinationStations.DayOfset' in 'where clause'

Comment: Once I paste this on mysql it gives me an sql syntax error

`SELECT
    bds.FromStationPositionID
FROM
    BusDestinationSegments AS bds
LEFT JOIN BusDestinationSegmentPrices AS bdsp ON bds.SegmentID = bdsp.BusDestinationSegmentID
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        BusDestinationScheduleID
    FROM
        BusDestinationSchedule
    WHERE
        BusDestinationScheduleDate + INTERVAL bdssf.DayOfset DAY = '2016-01-26'
)(BusDestinationStations AS bdssf)`

Comment: Try using this query

Comment: The result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using a mix of old and new JOIN syntax. And expecting BusDestinationStations (which is bdssf from which the DayOfset column comes) to CROSS JOIN.

This used to work but one of the changes in MySQL 5.6 is to the precedence of the joins:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html :-

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3)). This change affects statements
>   that use an ON clause, because that clause can refer only to columns
>   in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes
>   interpretation of what those operands are.

So I think what is happening is that MySQL is trying to perform the processing of the sub query before the implicit join to BusDestinationStations, and as such it doesn't know anything about bdssf.DayOfset when the sub query is executed.

Think the following would be the equivalent of what you are trying to do:-

```
SELECT bds.FromStationPositionID
FROM BusDestinationSegments AS bds
CROSS JOIN BusDestinationStations AS bdssf
LEFT JOIN BusDestinationSegmentPrices AS bdsp ON bds.SegmentID = bdsp.BusDestinationSegmentID
AND EXISTS 
(
    SELECT BusDestinationScheduleID
    FROM BusDestinationSchedule
    WHERE BusDestinationScheduleDate + INTERVAL bdssf.DayOfset DAY = '2016-01-26'
)
```

(although I am a bit dubious about doing a cross join like that just to get values for the sub query - looks very inefficient).

Comment: The same statement also occurs in 5.5 version of the documentation - but it is bad practice mixing the old & new style joins & I agree with your theory of what is happening

Comment: Thank you, it worked beautifully. Excellent explanation!